# Regex to match various temp path but not template

Tags: regex

I'm use a regex to catch users temp directories, but avoid matching template. Using a single regex - if possible.

The regex should match `temp*` variations but not `template`.

```
/db/Sales/tempq/somethingelse
/db/Sales/temp1/something/else
/db/Sales/temp/somethingelse
/db/Sales/template/somethingelse
```

Any suggestion for such regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
\/db\/Sales\/temp(?!late).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/swEVXa/1

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^(?!.*\/template\/).*$
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/MuSIVf/1)

---

- `^` - beginning of string
- `(?!.*\/template\/)` - don't match if the string contains `/template/`
- `.*$` - match all until end of string.